# How to store 2D array in android shared preference in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, multidimensional-array

I want to store 2D array using shared preference ?

Here I am trying to store 2D array in shared preference from one activity and after that i can load it in another activity using previously stored 2D array but i am not able to store 2D array in shared preference.

```
   val _rMsg = intent.getStringArrayExtra(rKey)
    val inflater = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    val parent = _class11_

    val _arData = arrayListOf<Array<String>>()
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val gson = Gson()

    val backJson = sharedPreferences.getString("task_li",null)

    val type = TypeToken<ArrayList<>>() {}.type

    _arData.add(gson.fromJson(backJson,type))

    try {



        _arData.add(_rMsg)


        val edit = sharedPreferences.edit()
        val json = gson.toJson(_arData)
        edit.putString("task_li",json)
        edit.apply()


       for (i in _arData) {
           val cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout._preset_layout, null)
           val mT = cardView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id._title__)
           mT.text = i[0].toString()
           parent.addView(cardView)
       }


   } catch (ex: Exception) {

   }
```

Comment: if u need to pass data from one screen to another screen then no need to save data in shared preference. If u are using kotlin then use jetpack navigation for transfer model class from one screen to other screen or use parceble class.

If any requirement for use same data in many screen and no update in data then u can save this data in shared preference

Comment: @NikunjPatel is being reasonable. Still if you want to use SharedPreferences, you can transform the array to a comma separated values string then save it.

Comment: I want to store in store so i was trying to get it stored in prefences first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use ObjectSerializer. [ https://github.com/apache/pig/blob/89c2e8e76c68d0d0abe6a36b4e08ddc56979796f/src/org/apache/pig/impl/util/ObjectSerializer.java ] this awesome class permit you to simple serialize and deserialize every kind of object, so you can simply save them as string into shared. You can store it like this :

```
    val mArrayTest = arrayListOf<Array<String>>()
    mArrayTest.add(arrayOf("1","3"))
    mArrayTest.add(arrayOf("2","4"))

    edit.putString("mArrayTest",ObjectSerializer.serialize(mArrayTest)).commit()
```

and get it like this :

```
  val mTestStr = pref.getString("mArrayTest",null)
  if (mTestStr != null) {
        val mTestStr2 = ObjectSerializer.deserialize(mTestStr) as ArrayList<Array<String>>
        Toast.makeText(this, mTestStr2[0][1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     }
```